# Requests library: Passing boolean values in params

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have this code which sends request to an API

```
request_parameters = {
    "headers": myheaders,
    "params": { "myparam": True }
}        

response = requests.get(myurl, **request_parameters)
```

Value of `response.url` is `myurl?myparam=True` - But the API expects lowercase string `"true"`.

Do I really have to manually convert all boolean values in dict to strings `"false"` and `"true"`? Isn`t there a better way? I expected that requests library converts it to json before converting it to a string.

Comment: *requests* will build a query string out of the *params* dictionary. It will not apply any conversions other than URL encoding

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution now:

```
def helper_convert_booleans_in_dict_to_lowercase_strings(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, bool):
            d[k] = str(v).lower()
        elif isinstance(v, list):  # check if the value is a list
            d[k] = [str(item).lower() if isinstance(item, bool) else item for item in v]
    return d
```

I can then do:

```
request_parameters = {
    "headers": myheaders,
    "params": helper_convert_booleans_in_dict_to_lowercase_strings({ "myparam": True })
}
```

But I hate it. Any better idea? Are there other datatypes which can cause stupid things?